# Why replaceAll() removes an extra character

Tags: java, regex

I'm using replaceAll() to remove all the "00" from the given String. Though it's removing all the 00, it is also removing a preceding character.

```
String a = "2400.00";
String a1 = a.replaceAll(".00", "");
```

I expected 24 as o/p but got 2.

Comment: Because [`String.replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) accept a regex. `"."` means any character. I vote to close since this is just a typo.

Comment: Why whould you expect 24 from 2400.00 by removing .00 ?

Comment: I think replace takes the number of occurrences you can give how many char you want your replace replace all will replace all the char as it takes regex and . Means everything

Comment: So, if you remove _all the "00" form the given String_, you would get `"24."` but you expect `"24"`. What is exactly your expectation here ?

Comment: If you want to match the trailing zeroes and the following dot with 2 zeroes for decimal values try `(?<!\S)(\d+?)0*\.00(?!\S)` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/qsh0V6/1) and replace with the first capturing group `$1`

Answer (score 4):

The `.` means any character in regex. `replaceAll` uses a regex as arugment. Please escape it. `a.replaceAll("\\.00", "");`

Or just simply use `replace(".00", "")`.

Comment: why would not use `replace` instead ?

Comment: If he is expecting more then on possible occurance `replaceAll` is the right choice. If you know it is only present once you can use `replace`

Comment: That is incorrect, `replace` Also replaces ALL occurrences - as per javadocs *Replaces each substring of this string that matches the literal target sequence with the specified literal replacement sequence.*

Comment: @ScaryWombat You are right. `replace` would be easier indeed.

Answer (score 2):

`replaceAll` takes regex as first argument. In regex sytax `.`(dot) means ANY character, thus the result.

Either escape that dot with `\\` or use `replace` instead of `replaceAll` (replace still replaces all occurences, but argument is "pattern" to replace, not regex)

Comment: But I don't know what is the expectation as removing literally .00 will not give him 24 as he stated that is what he expect.

Comment: I think `replace` is what the OP is after.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `.` cmatches any character in regex (well, except for the newline character, but it can be changed with appropriate flag).

That's why it matches `400` as well as `.00` and replaces it.

What you need is to replace `00` or `.00`, so you need pattern: `\.?00`

Explanation:

`\.?` - match `.` zero or one time

`00` - match `00` literally

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/MCmkJs/1)

Code:

```
String a = "2400.00";
String a1 = a.replaceAll("\\.?00", "");
System.out.println(a1);
```